# Proof verification related to the Intermediate value theorem.

Tags: calculus, solution-verification, learning

Suppose that f is a continuous function on [0, 2] such that f(0) = f(2). Show
that there is a real number ξ ∈ [1, 2] with f(ξ) = f(ξ − 1).

ξ ∈ [1, 2], ξ-1 ∈ [0, 1]
Case 1: if f(0)=f(1) then ξ = 2, f(ξ) = f(0)= f(1) = f(2) therefore f(ξ)= f(ξ-1)=f(2)=f(1)

Case 2: if f(0)>f(1) then f(2) > f(1). By continuity there must exist some m where f(2) ≥ m ≥ f(1) and by IMV theorem there exists some ξ ∈ [1, 2] where f(ξ)=m. Now, ξ-1 ∈ [0, 1] and by continuity there must also exist the same m, f(0)≥ m ≥ f(1). Therefore by IMV theorem again there must exist at least 1 value where f(ξ − 1) = m and since m is common there must exist at least 1 value where f(ξ − 1) = f(ξ).

Case 3: f(1)>f(0). This is pretty much the same thing as case 2.

-This is a very difficult calculus question and I've never written a proof and I'm in Algebra II. Pls don't flame me if this is very stupid.

Comment: In your Case 2, it is true that there is some $\xi \in [1,2]$ such that $f(\xi)=m$, and some $\xi' \in [0, 1]$ such that $f(\xi') = m$, but you haven't really shown that $\xi' = \xi-1$ necessarily holds.

Comment: Try defining $g(x) = f(x)-f(x-1)$ for $x \in [1, 2]$ and apply the IVT on $g$ instead of on $f$.

Comment: There does appear to be a problem, in that the $\xi$ for $f(\xi)=m$ and the $\xi$ for $f(\xi-1)=m$ do not appear to be necessarily the same. You could perhaps try looking at $g(x)=f(x)-f(x-1)$ for $x$ in [1,2].

Comment: You can make the argument for case 3 more formal by defining $h(\xi)=-f(\xi)$. If your argument applies to any function with a greater value at 1 than at 0, then it applies to $h$, and so the result is true for $f$. That said, most people would just say "a similar argument applies when f(1)>f(0)".

Answer (score 4):

Your Case 2 proof, and therefore Case 3 proof too, looks dodgy. You correctly find $\xi\in[1,2]$ with $f(\xi) = m$. Also correctly, you note that $m$ is in the image of $[0,1]$ under $f$: there is *some* $\gamma\in[0,1]$ with $f(\gamma) = m$. You can even write $\gamma$ as $\xi'-1$ for some $\xi'\in[1,2]$. However, you're not entitled to conclude that $\xi' = \xi$.

A simpler approach: consider the function $g\colon[1,2]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}: \xi\mapsto f(\xi) - f(\xi-1)$. Then $g(2) = - g(1)$, so by continuity and IMV there is $\xi \in[1,2]$ such that $g(\xi) = 0$.

Comment: Thanks for the help and I can clearly follow that solution however one thing I struggle with is knowing how to start and I was just wondering if there is any way to prove it using a corrected form of my method?

Comment: @Matty33Anderson you're very welcome. I don't see how to get across the finish line with your method. You're looking for $\xi$ such that $f(\xi) - f(\xi-1) = 0$, and you have to consider all possible $\xi$. If you just pick a single $m\in f([1,2])$, say $m = f(\gamma), \gamma\in[1,2]$, it's true that $m$ is also in $f([0,1])$, say $m = f(\xi), \xi\in[0,1]$, but you have no control over the distance $\gamma - \xi$.

Comment: @Matty33Anderson Feel free to call it a correct answer ;)